# get separate result from returning array in codeigniter

Tags: select, nested, codeigniter-2

```
I would like to tell you that I am stuck in the simple logic.I know it is so simple but I need a help this time.

I have an array <strong>$allCategories</strong> that returns data from db table. ( select * from tablename) 
Structure is like this:
```

==================================================================
ID     CATEGORY NAME    DESCRIPTION    PARENT CATEGORY
 ==================================================================
    1             ABCD                   lorem ipsum                   2
    2               JKL                    lorem ipsum                    0
    3             WXYZ                  lorem ipsum                    1

```
I want to show Category name instead of digits.Actually The digits are the Id of the Cateogry name. 
Like JKL comes instead of 2 and ABCD instead of 1.
<?php $i =1;
    foreach($allCategories as $ab){
 ?>
  <tr class="pointer">
  <td class=" "><?php echo $i ?></td>
   <td class=" "><?php echo $ab['category_name'] ?></td>
   <td class=" "><?php echo $ab['category_description']; ?></td>
   <td class=" ">
    <?php
        $parent_category = $ab['parent_category'];
        return $this->db->select('category_name')
        ->from('categories')
         ->where('id', $parent_category)
        ->get()
        ->row();
        //echo $ab['parent_category'] 
    ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
       $i++;
       }                            
    ?>
```

If you want any information or query regarding my ques. ask me.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use "return" here. Change it like this:

```
echo $this->db->select('category_name')
    ->from('categories')
     ->where('id', $parent_category)
    ->get()
    ->row()["category_name"];
```

Comment: row() method returns an array with table columns and values